# Calculate the operator norm of the difference of two operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $x_1,...,x_n \in [0,1]$, $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $S,T : C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ be the operators defined by

$T(g)= \int_0^1 g(s)\, ds$

and

$S(g) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i g(x_i)$.

$C([0,1])$ is equipped with the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$-norm.

I already proved that $\|T\| = 1$ and $\|S\| = \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|$, where I used for the $\geq $-inequality the function $\tilde{g}$, which satisfies $\tilde{g}(x_i) = \dfrac{\bar{\lambda_i}}{|\lambda_i|}$ for all $i=1,...,n$ and is linearly interpolated between the $x_i$.

Now I want to find the norm of the operator $R:=T-S$.
We obviously have

$\|R\| \leq \|T\|+\|S\| = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|$

and

$\|R\| \geq |\|T\|-\|S\|| = |1-\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i||$.

How can I proceed now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The norm of $R$ is equal to the upper bound you calculated: define a continuous function which is $\pm 1$ at $x_i$ and equal to $1$ at point with distance $\epsilon$ to all $x_i$. Then let $\epsilon\searrow0$.